# mudar cor dos componentes da pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

Ola
Estou procurando uma forma de fazer o seguinte.
Tenho esse código abaixo... e quero um botão que mude as cores dos elementos nele,
tipo a cor do fundo, a cor da letra, a cor do fundo da faixa. Seria uma mudança 
que o próprio usuário vai fazer, ele escolhe a cor que quer em cada elemento.
Se tiver um jeito de fazer sem ser usando java seria bom mas se for só com java 
mesmo é bom também pq assim eu aprendo mais kkk

```css
body {
    background-color: #2f45d6;  
}
h1 {
    background-color: #a30000;
  color: #fffb00;
  padding: 15px; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h1>ola mundo!</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou clara, vc quer clicar no box vermelho colocar uma cor que escolher, depois quer clicar no texto e escolher outro cor etc... é isso?

Comment: Eu queria fazer com cores pré definidas como por exemplo: teria um quadrado que esta dividido em 3 cores (azul,amarelo e vermelho) e quando o usuário clicar nesse quadrado o fundo fica azul, a faixa amarela e a letra vermelha. Eteria uns 3-4 quadrados do mesmo tipo com cores diferentes que quando clicado muda as cores do fundo, da faixa e da letra nas cores que estão no quadro. É como se tivesse escolhendo um tema em uma IDE por exemplo, que ao invés de trocar componente por componente e já traz uma pré definição de cores de cada componente em apenas um click

Answer (score 1):

Acho que vc pode fazer alguma coisa parecida com isso
Adicionando um input color e javascript.
Eu fiz so para o h1 mas ai vc pode ir adaptando para os outros elementos.

```js
document.getElementById("colormenu").oninput=function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.color=this.value;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2f45d6;  
}
h1 {
  background-color: #a30000;
  color: #fffb00;
  padding: 15px; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>ola mundo!</h1>
<input type="color" id="colormenu">
```

**EDIT**
Com botao ficaria algo mais ou menos assim,  ja que vc tem as cores pre definidas

```
document.getElementById("color").onclick=function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style="background-color:red";
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style="background-color:yellow";
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.color="blue";
}
```

Comment: Seria quase isso mesmo porem eu queria fazer com cores pré definidas como por exemplo: teria um quadrado que esta dividido em 3 cores (azul,amarelo e vermelho) e quando o usuário clicar nesse quadrado o fundo fica azul, a faixa amarela e a letra vermelha. Eteria uns 3-4 quadrados do mesmo tipo com cores diferentes que quando clicado muda as cores do fundo, da faixa e da letra nas cores que estão no quadro. É como se tivesse escolhendo um tema em uma IDE por exemplo, que ao invés de trocar componente por componente e já traz uma pré definição de cores de cada componente em apenas um click

Comment: Ai a ideia eh a mesma. Vc vai ter os botoes ai ao inves de oninput vc usa o onclick e muda a cor conforme vc queira. Se eu puder mais tarde eu edito a resposta.

Comment: será que não seria melhor uma estrutura condicional, do tipo "se clicar nesse botar os elementos ficam de uma cor, se clicar no outro eles ficam de outra cor diferente". Porque eu quero colocar uma escolha para o usuário porem uma escolha pré definida.

Comment: Editei a resposta vê se eh isso.